# How to be resistant to ordering?

Tags: haskell, parsec

Given input in form `A,B,C` where the order is not fixed (eg `C,B,A` might be possible too), how would I parse the string into a tuple `(a,b,c)` so that the result is ordered again?

Bigger example:

Input A:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

Input B:

```
C 3
B 2
A 1
```

Parsers:

```
a = "A " *> decimal
b = "B " *> decimal
c = "C " *> decimal
```

How do I write a parser that will give `(1,2,3)` for Input A and B.

Edit: I have to more exact: they aren't all decimals ... Else `choice` would be the combinator of choice here.

Comment: Why not simply sort `B` before parsing?

Comment: Because they are part of an input stream. Several lines come in as a package, but I can't be sure of the order of the lines in it.

Comment: Then sort the result at the end? You can't have the items in sorted order without knowing about every item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Text.Parsec.Perm](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Perm.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Perm
import Control.Applicative

a = ...
b = ...
c = ...

p = permute ( 
      (,,) <$$> a <||> b <||> c)
```

Comment: That looks perfect. I'll try it asap and accept this if it works for me.

Comment: There is no version of this for `attoparsec` is there?

Comment: @augustss: Yes, it does (the types combine in a way similar to the `f <$> x <*> y <*> z` idiom).

Comment: @Florian: There are several packages on Hackage that work with any `Alternative`: [actions-permutations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/action-permutations), [perm](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/perm), [permute](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/permute) (I haven't tried either).

Comment: From a quick test it seems that this is working. Is there any knowledge about the performance impact of this?