# How to parse unordered syntax

Tags: haskell, parsec

```
newtype Program = Program [Global] [Function]
```

I am parsing a source file with C-like syntax in Haskell, where global variables and functions are present at top level. It's straightforward to parse if they must come in order, say, functions after all global variables. But they can come in any order as shown below. How to handle syntax like this?

> global0
>
> function0
>
> global1
>
> function1
>
> function2
>
> global2

Seems sth like Parsec.Perm can be used, but [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331100/how-to-be-resistant-to-ordering) works when all choices return the same type (**decimal**), where as my case returns either **Global** or **Function**.

Comment: `data Declaration = DeclGlobal Global | DeclFunction Function`.

Comment: As for permutation parsing: It applies when you want at most one of each thing, in any order. Since you want to allow any number of each, it's actually an easier problem to solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a permutation parser. Simple old `many` is fine. You can use `Either` to temporarily make them the same type, then `partitionEithers` to split them back out.

```
uncurry Program . partitionEithers
    <$> many (  (Left  <$> parseGlobal)
            <|> (Right <$> parseFunction)
             )
```

Edit: alternately, you could make them all be `Program`s and then combine them. Something like

```
instance Monoid Program where mempty = Program [] []
instance Semigroup Program where
    Program gs fs <> Program gs' fs' = Program (gs <> gs') (fs <> fs')

global x = Program [x] []
function x = Program [] [x]
```

and then use:

```
fold <$> many ((global <$> parseGlobal) <|> (function <$> parseFunction))
```

Very similar program structure, but maybe one or the other is more aesthetically appealing to you.